# Setting the correct content-type in HTML web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-type

I'm coding in JavaScript. I'm using Gitbash and node, to create a local-hosted server on port 1337. Also using Windows if that helps.

I'm trying to display an image on my localhost, and that works fine. I have a index.html file with code to display a jpeg file. That works fine, however when I inspect the page in chrome, the content type is set to "text/html", when I need it to be image/jpeg.

I tried the following code, but it stopped the page from loading entirely.

```
if(filename === "./index.html") {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

Any ideas on what I could try to set the correct content-type?
*EDIT* Our directions are to "display the file and to return the file to the user by setting the correct Content-Type for the file and writing it to the response"

Comment: Well text/html is the correct mime when loading a html file. Setting the content type to an image mime when the content isn't actually an image would stop the browser from loading it correctly as it isn't an image.

Comment: @PatrickEvans so do I need to change the file to image.jpeg? or image.jpg

Comment: If you are wanting to display an image why arent you just sending the image?

Comment: @PatrickEvans This is for an assignment. He wants the image displayed but also wants us to "Return the file to the user by setting the correct Content-Type for the file and writing it to the response"

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks, followed the duplicate and this worked!